# serf: Query queue depth warning endless counting up, no documentation on source of error

Tags: linux, go, etcd

As of yesterday we started receiving this error in between job runs that endlessly counts upwards (so far has reached 1245 before manual restart)

We are running Dkron job scheduler with ETCD as the backend.

Example error:

> INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:39+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:39 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218

There seems to be no documentation or help to understand this I have been able to find. If anyone knows what is causing this, or any more information about it I would be very grateful!

Below I will add a copy of the logs in greater detail in case any of it might help. Again thanks so much! (and apologies if I have not provided enough information, I am unsure of what information would be important as I do not know the source of this error)

```
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:49+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:49 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:50+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:50 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:51+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:51 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:52+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:52 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:53+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:53 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:54+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:54 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:55+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:55 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:56+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:56 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:57+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:57 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:58+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:58 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:03:59+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:03:59 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 218 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] scheduler: Run job                            job=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main schedule="0 4 * * * *"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] scheduler: Run job                            job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main schedule="0 */2 * * * *"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Retrieved job from datastore           job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Filtered nodes to run: []              node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Filtered tags to run: map[]            node=Dkron_Main
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Sending query                          job_name=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Sending query                          job_name=2minute_jobs json="{\"execution\":{\"job_name\":\"2minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"group\":1550131440007370602,\"attempt\":1},\"rpc_addr\":\"127.0.0.1:6868\"}" node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received event                         event="query: run:job" node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Running job                            at=219 node=Dkron_Main payload="{\"execution\":{\"job_name\":\"2minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"group\":1550131440007370602,\"attempt\":1},\"rpc_addr\":\"127.0.0.1:6868\"}" query="run:job"
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Starting job                           job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] scheduler: Run job                            job=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main schedule="0 * * * * *"
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:00 [DEBUG] serf: messageQueryResponseType: Dkron_Main 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received ack                           from=Dkron_Main node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Retrieved job from datastore           job=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Filtered nodes to run: []              node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Filtered tags to run: map[]            node=Dkron_Main
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Sending query                          job_name=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Sending query                          job_name=60minute_jobs json="{\"execution\":{\"job_name\":\"60minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"group\":1550131440007318183,\"attempt\":1},\"rpc_addr\":\"127.0.0.1:6868\"}" node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:00 [DEBUG] serf: messageQueryResponseType: Dkron_Main 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received ack                           from=Dkron_Main node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Retrieved job from datastore           job=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Filtered nodes to run: []              node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Filtered tags to run: map[]            node=Dkron_Main
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Sending query                          job_name=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Sending query                          job_name=1minute_jobs json="{\"execution\":{\"job_name\":\"1minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"group\":1550131440027758329,\"attempt\":1},\"rpc_addr\":\"127.0.0.1:6868\"}" node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:00 [DEBUG] serf: messageQueryResponseType: Dkron_Main 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received ack                           from=Dkron_Main node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] grpc: Received GetJob                         job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Retrieved job from datastore           job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: GetJob by RPC                          job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received event                         event="query: run:job" node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Running job                            at=220 node=Dkron_Main payload="{\"execution\":{\"job_name\":\"60minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"group\":1550131440007318183,\"attempt\":1},\"rpc_addr\":\"127.0.0.1:6868\"}" query="run:job"
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Starting job                           job=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] invoke: calling executor plugin               node=Dkron_Main plugin=shell
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:00 [DEBUG] serf: messageQueryResponseType: Dkron_Main 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received response                      from=Dkron_Main node=Dkron_Main query="run:job" response="{\"job_name\":\"2minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"2019-02-14T10:04:00.126925316+02:00\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"node_name\":\"Dkron_Main\",\"group\":1550131440007370602,\"attempt\":1}"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Setting key                            execution=1550131440126925316-Dkron_Main job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] shell: going to run bash /home/benemenadmin/dkron_jobs/bash/2minute_jobs.sh  node=Dkron_Main subsystem_name=plugins.dkron-executor-shell
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: to detele key                          execution=1550119440072343171-Dkron_Main job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] grpc: Received GetJob                         job=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Retrieved job from datastore           job=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: GetJob by RPC                          job=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received event                         event="query: run:job" node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Running job                            at=221 node=Dkron_Main payload="{\"execution\":{\"job_name\":\"1minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"group\":1550131440027758329,\"attempt\":1},\"rpc_addr\":\"127.0.0.1:6868\"}" query="run:job"
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Starting job                           job=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] invoke: calling executor plugin               node=Dkron_Main plugin=shell
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:00 [DEBUG] serf: messageQueryResponseType: Dkron_Main 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received response                      from=Dkron_Main node=Dkron_Main query="run:job" response="{\"job_name\":\"60minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"2019-02-14T10:04:00.202107834+02:00\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"node_name\":\"Dkron_Main\",\"group\":1550131440007318183,\"attempt\":1}"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Setting key                            execution=1550131440202107834-Dkron_Main job=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] shell: going to run bash /home/benemenadmin/dkron_jobs/bash/60minute_jobs.sh  node=Dkron_Main subsystem_name=plugins.dkron-executor-shell
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: to detele key                          execution=1549757040048767013-Dkron_Main job=60minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] grpc: Received GetJob                         job=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Retrieved job from datastore           job=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: GetJob by RPC                          job=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] invoke: calling executor plugin               node=Dkron_Main plugin=shell
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] shell: going to run bash /home/benemenadmin/dkron_jobs/bash/1minute_jobs.sh  node=Dkron_Main subsystem_name=plugins.dkron-executor-shell
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:00 [DEBUG] serf: messageQueryResponseType: Dkron_Main 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] agent: Received response                      from=Dkron_Main node=Dkron_Main query="run:job" response="{\"job_name\":\"1minute_jobs\",\"started_at\":\"2019-02-14T10:04:00.316814676+02:00\",\"finished_at\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"node_name\":\"Dkron_Main\",\"group\":1550131440027758329,\"attempt\":1}"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: Setting key                            execution=1550131440316814676-Dkron_Main job=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] store: to detele key                          execution=1550125380180647982-Dkron_Main job=1minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:00+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:00 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:01+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:01 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:02+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:02 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:03+02:00] agent: Done receiving acks and responses      node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:03+02:00] agent: Done receiving acks and responses      node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:03+02:00] agent: Done receiving acks and responses      node=Dkron_Main query="run:job"
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:03+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:03 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:04+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:04 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:05+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:05 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:06+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:06 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:07+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:07 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:07+02:00] shell: Command output                         node=Dkron_Main subsystem_name=plugins.dkron-executor-shell
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:07+02:00]                                               node=Dkron_Main subsystem_name=plugins.dkron-executor-shell
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:07+02:00] 2Minute_Jobs complete                         node=Dkron_Main subsystem_name=plugins.dkron-executor-shell
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:07+02:00]                                               node=Dkron_Main subsystem_name=plugins.dkron-executor-shell
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:07+02:00] grpc: Received execution done                 group=1550131440007370602 job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:07+02:00] store: Retrieved job from datastore           job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:07+02:00] store: Setting key                            execution=1550131440126925316-Dkron_Main job=2minute_jobs node=Dkron_Main
DEBU[2019-02-14T10:04:08+02:00] grpc: from: Dkron_Main                        node=Dkron_Main
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:08+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:08 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:09+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:09 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:10+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:10 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:11+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:11 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:12+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:12 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:13+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:13 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:14+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:14 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:15+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:15 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:16+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:16 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221 
INFO[2019-02-14T10:04:17+02:00] 2019/02/14 10:04:17 [WARN] serf: Query queue depth: 221
```